# KeyError and out of index issue in the code

Tags: python, json

I'm running the following code along with some other, but I'm facing some issues with this part.

```
idx_to_movie = {}
with open('u.item', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        info = line.split('|')
        idx_to_movie[int(info[0])-1] = info[4]

def top_k_movies(similarity, mapper, movie_idx, k=6):
    return [mapper[x] for x in np.argsort(similarity[movie_idx,:])[:-k-1:-1]]

idx = 0 # Toy Story
movies = top_k_movies(item_similarity, idx_to_movie, idx)
posters = tuple(Image(url=get_poster(movie, base_url)) for movie in movies)
```

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

```
 <ipython-input-78-17abeb8d67ed> in 
 get_poster(imdb_url, base_url)
```

try:
file_path = json.loads(response.text)['posters'][0]['file_path']
       except:

KeyError: 'posters'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

```
 <ipython-input-85-a456f8efd408> in <module>()
 idx = 0 # Toy Story   
 movies = top_k_movies(item_similarity, idx_to_movie, idx)
 posters = tuple(Image(url=get_poster(movie, base_url)) for movie in movies)

<ipython-input-85-a456f8efd408> in <genexpr>(.0)
idx = 0 # Toy Story
movies = top_k_movies(item_similarity, idx_to_movie, idx)
posters = tuple(Image(url=get_poster(movie, base_url)) for movie in movies)
```

in

```
  get_poster(imdb_url, base_url)
  payload['query'] = movie_title
  response = requests.get('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie', params=payload, headers=headers)
  movie_id = json.loads(response.text)['results'][0]['id']
  payload.pop('query', None)
  movie_url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{:}/images'.format(movie_id)
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: [link] : http://blog.ethanrosenthal.com/2015/11/02/intro-to-collaborative-filtering/.   I have made some edits to this link, but nothing significant to the problem I'm facing.

Comment: I would suggest putting an if statement around `file_path = json.loads(response.text)['posters'][0]['file_path']` to make sure response code was 200. Just to make sure you're getting the page.

Comment: Your `try except` statements do not look correct. It is hard to tell because of the break in code formatting in the question. But from what I can tell you are not actually catching exceptions the way you expect you are